# Dynamo DB (Calculated Attrbutes)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

i'm looking at using AWS Amplify Data Model / Dynamo DB to create a fantasy football app via way of learning.

I'm just getting to grips with NoSQL v SQL and its sort of making sense but im not sure if Dynamo DB can do calculations like an RDB

The one thing I cant seem to find is the equivalent of calculated columns in Dynamo DB. For example if i had a scoring system reference table how would one use that to run calculations against users' submitted teams in DynamoDB/AWS land? Is it even possible to calculate between 2 item attributes?

Is Dynamo DB not suitable for this type of application? Should i just forget NoSQL and use a relational DB?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB addresses this use case with [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html), which produce change events that a compute target can act on.  The target is responsible for the calculations and table updates.

Set a [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) as the table's Streams target, for instance, and the function will be invoked when [filterable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial2.html) table change events occur. It receives the item change details in the payload.  The Lambda would then calculate and write back any "calculated column" values to the table with SDK calls.

See the AWS blogpost [DynamoDB Streams Use Cases and Design Patterns](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/).  AWS has since added [EventBridge Pipes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-dynamodb.html) as a Streams target.

Comment: Thanks for your response - that clarifies a lot. Cheers